# Implementation of nextafter functionality in R

Tags: r, floating-point

Is there any implementation of functionality in R, such that it is possible to get the next representable floating point number from a given floating point number. This would be similar to the [nextafter](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/nextafter.html) function in the C standard library. Schemes such as `number + .Machine$double.eps` don't work in general.

Answer (score 5):

No, but there are two ways you can make it:

**Using C**

If you want the exact functionality of the `nextafter()` function, you can write a C function that works as an interface to the function such that the following two constraints are met:

- The function does not return a value. All work is accomplished as a "side effect" (changing the values of arguments).
- All the arguments are pointers. Even scalars are vectors (of length one) in R.

That function should then be compiled as a shared library:

```
R CMD SHLIB foo.c
```

for UNIX-like OSs.  The shared library can be called using `dyn.load("foo.so")`.  You can then call the function from inside R using the `.C()` function

```
.C("foo", ...)
```

A more in depth treatment of calling C from R is [here](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~geyer/rc/).

**Using R**

`number + .Machine$double.eps` is the way to go but you have to consider edge cases, such as if `x - y < .Machine$double.eps` or if `x == y`.  I would write the function like this:

```
nextafter <- function(x, y){
  # Appropriate type checking and bounds checking goes here
  delta = y - x
  if(x > 0){
    factor = 2^floor(log2(x)) + ifelse(x >= 4, 1, 0)
      } else if (x < 0) {
    factor = 65
  }
  if (delta > .Machine$double.eps){
    return(x + factor * .Machine$double.eps)
  } else if (delta < .Machine$double.eps){
    return(x - factor * .Machine$double.eps)
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
}
```

Now, unlike C, if you want to check integers, you can do so in the same function but you need to change the increment based on the type.

**UPDATE**
The previous code did not perform as expected for numbers larger than 2.  There is a factor that needs to be multiplied by the `.Machine$double.eps` to make it large enough to cause the numbers to be different.  It is related to the nearest power of 2 plus one.  You can get an idea of how this works with the below code:

```
n <- -100
factor <- vector('numeric', 100)
for(i in 1:n){
  j = 0
  while(TRUE){
    j = j + 1
    if(i - j * .Machine$double.eps != i) break()
  }
  factor[i] = j
}
```

Comment: do you want a `(delta < .Machine$double.eps)` after your `else if` ?

Comment: In your second condition, should you use `.Machine$double.neg.eps`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was expecting native calls would be needed. Unfortunately with the R, this doesn't work, `100 + .Machine$double.eps == 100` is `TRUE`.

Comment: @RónánDaly: you can do it all in R, but you have to add a factor for .Machine$double.eps.  It only guarantees the next representable number for 1.  For other numbers, you have to make it bigger.  I have added some code to fix that so it should work between -100 and 100 for integers.  More testing would be needed though.

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double nextAfter(double x, double y) {
   return nextafter(x, y);
}
```

Then in R:

```
sprintf("%.20f", 1)
#[1] "1.00000000000000000000"
sprintf("%.20f", nextAfter(1, 2))
#[1] "1.00000000000000022204"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Christopher Louden's answer works for all values, but here's a pure R version of the classic approach (increments/decrements the integer bits). R does not make it easy to convert between doubles and integers, nor does it have a 64-bit integer type, so there's quite a lot of code for this.

```
doubleToRaw <- function(d) writeBin(d, raw());
rawToDouble <- function(r) readBin(r, numeric());
int64inc <- function(lo, hi) {
  if (lo == 0xffffffff) { hi <- hi + 1; lo <- 0; } else { lo <- lo + 1; }
  return(c(lo, hi));
}
int64dec <- function(lo, hi) {
  if (lo == 0) { hi <- hi - 1; lo <- 0xffffffff; } else { lo <- lo - 1; }
  return(c(lo, hi));
}

nextafter <- function(x, y) {
  if (is.nan(x + y))
    return(NaN);
  if (x == y)
    return(x);
  if (x == 0)
    return(sign(y) * rawToDouble(as.raw(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1))));
  ints <- packBits(rawToBits(doubleToRaw(x)), "integer")
  if ((y > x) == (x > 0))
    ints <- int64inc(ints[1], ints[2])
  else
    ints <- int64dec(ints[1], ints[2]);
  return(rawToDouble(packBits(intToBits(ints), "raw")))
}
```