# Compare floats in R

Tags: r, floating-point, precision

**Disclaimer**

I was not sure whether to post that here or on [CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) but after having read what [is on topic on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I think it is more `R` specific then purely statistical. Thus, I posted it here.

**Problem**

Citing from `?.Machine`

> `double.eps`
>   the smallest positive floating-point number `x` such that `1 + x != 1`. It equals `double.base ^ ulp.digits` if either `double.base` is 2 or `double.rounding` is 0; otherwise, it is `(double.base ^ double.ulp.digits) / 2`. Normally `2.220446e-16`.

Thus, I would assume that `all.equal(1 + .Machine$double.eps, 1.0)` returns `FALSE`. Which it does not. Reading the doc of  `all.equal` I see that the default tolerance is `.Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5`.

Fair enough, but I observe some odd results which I do not understand:

```
isTRUE(all.equal(1.0 + .Machine$double.eps, 1.0, tolerance = .Machine$double.eps)) # TRUE
isTRUE(all.equal(1.0 - .Machine$double.eps, 1.0, tolerance = .Machine$double.eps)) # FALSE
isTRUE(all.equal(0.9 + .Machine$double.eps, 0.9, tolerance = .Machine$double.eps)) # FALSE
isTRUE(all.equal(2.0 + .Machine$double.eps, 2.0, tolerance = .Machine$double.eps)) # TRUE
```

Thus, `all.equal` picks only differences for numbers below 1 correctly.

Last explanation I could think of is that `all.equal` looks on the *[relative difference scale](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/all.equal)*  by default, so I tried to overrule this behaviour with no success either:

```
isTRUE(all.equal(1.0 + .Machine$double.eps, 1.0, 
                 tolerance = .Machine$double.eps, scale = 1)) # TRUE
```

Apparently, I have a massive misunderstanding of how floating-point numbers work in `R`, which leads me to these

**Questions**

- How to compare 2 numbers in R with "maximum" (wrt to floating point precision) precision correctly?
- Why are the results of `all.equal` different for numbers below and above `1`?
- [Bonus Question]: what is the rational to use `.Machine$double.eps ^ .5` as default tolerance instead of the unsquarerooted version? Is it simply to relax the test a bit?

Comment: Have a look at [What is the correct/standard way to check if difference is smaller than machine precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59229545/10488504).

Comment: `Machine$double.eps` the smallest positive floating-point number `x` such that `1 + x != 1`. For `0.1 + x != 0.1` x is smaller than `Machine$double.eps` and for `100 + x != 100` x is larger than `Machine$double.eps`

Comment: To compare 2 numbers in R with "maximum" precision correctly use `==`.

Comment: Wow, thanks makes a lot of sense now. But why is `all.equal(1.0 + .Machine$double.eps, 1.0, tolerance = .Machine$double.eps)` still `TRUE`?

Comment: As you give here a tolerance of `.Machine$double.eps`.

Comment: Ah stupid me, of course  makes sense now. Would you bother to summarise your comments in an answer so I can accept them? Thanks for your enlightening!

Comment: “The smallest positive floating-point number `x` such that `1+x != 1` is an incorrect definition of `.Machine$double.eps`, even if the documentation says it. The correct definition is that it is the difference between 1 and the smallest representable value greater than 1, *i.e.*, the distance between representable values at the magnitude of 1. This is 2\*\*−52 in IEEE-754 binary64. With the incorrect definition,`x` would be 2\*\*−53+2\*\*−105, because adding this `x` to `1` results in a rounding up to the next representable value, 1+2\*\*−52.

Comment: There is **no** good general way to compare numbers that contain errors due to rounding, because the rounding errors that may occur can range from zero to infinity (or NaN) depending on the algorithms and data involved, so there can be no default tolerance that is generally correct, because any tolerance reduces false negatives at the expense of allowing false positives and that will have different consequences for different applications, and because making a tolerance too small will allow false negatives and that will have different consequences on different applications.

Comment: Re “[Bonus Question]: what is the rational to use .Machine$double.eps ^ .5 as default tolerance instead of the unsquarerooted version? Is it simply to relax the test a bit?”: The only rational is that a lot of people do simple things with floating-point, get only a few well-behaved rounding errors, and do not need to distinguish between numbers that would, if computed with real-number arithmetic, be very close but not equal. In essence, this default tolerance is suitable only for amateurs tinkering and breaks when complicated work is involved. Avoid using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Machine$double.eps` is the difference between 1 and the smallest representable value greater than 1. The difference between 0.1 and the smallest representable value greater than 0.1 is smaller than `.Machine$double.eps` and the difference between 100 and the smallest representable value greater than 100 is larger than `.Machine$double.eps`. Have a look at: [What is the correct/standard way to check if difference is smaller than machine precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59229545/10488504).

`.Machine$double.eps` is

```
.Machine$double.eps
[1] 2.220446e-16
```

When you make the calculations the intern sotred values will be approximately:

```
print(1.0 + .Machine$double.eps, 20)
#[1] 1.000000000000000222
print(1.0 - .Machine$double.eps, 20)
#[1] 0.99999999999999977796
print(0.9 + .Machine$double.eps, 20)
#[1] 0.90000000000000024425
print(2.0 + .Machine$double.eps, 20)
#[1] 2
```

Using `tolerance = .Machine$double.eps` `all.equal` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending if the difference of the intern stored values is lager or not than `tolerance`.

To compare 2 numbers in R if the are intern stored equal use `==`.

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't make sense. What is '"maximum" precision'? You should never compare calculated floating point numbers with ==.

Comment: I changed it to `if the are intern stored equal`.

Comment: “The smallest positive floating-point number `x` such that `1+x != 1` is an incorrect definition of `.Machine$double.eps`, even if the documentation says it. The correct definition is that it is the difference between 1 and the smallest representable value greater than 1, *i.e.*, the distance between representable values at the magnitude of 1. This is 2\*\*−52 in IEEE-754 binary64. With the incorrect definition,`x` would be 2\*\*−53+2\*\*−105, because adding this `x` to `1` results in a rounding up to the next representable value, 1+2\*\*−52.