# R: Computing maximum floating-point error for log(exp(...))

Tags: r, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I am working on some programming problems where I have to transition probabilities between standard space and log-space.  For this purpose, I am trying to find out the **maximum absolute error** for the floating-point error in `R` for the computation `log(exp(...))` where the input is a log-probability (i.e., a non-positive number).

At the moment I have computed the answer by using a grid search (see code and plot below), but I'm not sure if the value I've computed is correct.  (I checked some other ranges but the range shown in the plot seems to get the maximum absolute error.)

```
#Set function for computing floating-point error of log(exp(...))
fp.error <- function(x) { abs(log(exp(x)) - x) }

#Compute and plot floating-point error over a grid of non-negative values
xx <- -(0:20000/10000)
ff <- fp.error(xx)
plot(xx, ff, col = '#0000FF10',
     main = 'Error in computation of log(exp(...))', 
     xlab = 'x', ylab = 'Floating-Point Error')

#Compute maximum floating-point error
fp.error.max <- max(ff)
fp.error.max
[1] 1.110223e-16
```

[image]

From this analysis, my estimated maximum absolute error is half the size of `.Machine$double.eps` (which is `2.220446e-16`).  I am not sure if there is a theoretical reason for this, or if I am getting the wrong answer.

**Question:** Is there any way to determine if this is really the maximum floating-point error for this computation?  Is there any theoretical way to compute the maximum, or is this kind of grid-search method sufficient?

Comment: Are you only concerned with [0...2.0]?  What about larger values?

Comment: @chux: Edited --- I checked some other ranges but the one shown seems to get the biggest absolute error.

Comment: if you're working with log-probability/likelihood, then it's good to sway away from exponentiating if possible.  there are functions like `logsumexp` that allow you to stay in log-space where possible, see also `log1p` and `expm1` for more numerically stable functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got the right answer. Here I refined the step as small as `sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)`, you will see

```
> x <- seq(0, 2, by = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps))

> max(abs(log(exp(x)) - x))
[1] 1.110725e-16
```

However, once your `x` is extremely large, you will have `Inf` error, e.g.,

```
> (x <- .Machine$double.xmax)
[1] 1.797693e+308

> max(abs(log(exp(x)) - x))
[1] Inf
```

Comment: note that you'll get `Inf` for any `x > log(.Machine$double.xmax)`, i.e. around 710

Comment: @SamMason Yes. Actually `Inf` stems from `exp`, then `log(exp(x))` gives `Inf` in turn. I just want to show OP the possible error value.

Comment: note, I meant to suggest using `log` to recover the value that would cause `exp` to overflow

Comment: @SamMason It seems OP is not looking for workarounds but the possible errors by `log(exp(...))`. If OP wants to minimize the risk of errors, `exp(log(x))` should be applied instead.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding: Sorry to be a pain --- I just updated my question.  I'm actually dealing with inputs that are log-probabilities so they are non-positive (which might make a difference to your answer).

Answer (score 2):

The error of `log(exp(x))` depends on the value of `x`. If you use a *float* also x has an precision which depending on its value. The precission could be calculated with `nextafter` from `C`:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("double getPrec(double x) {
  return nextafter(x, std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()) - x;}")

getPrec(2)
#[1] 4.440892e-16

getPrec(exp(2))
#[1] 8.881784e-16
```

or not using `Rcpp`:

```
getPrecR <- function(x) {
  y <- log2(pmax(.Machine$double.xmin, abs(x)))
  ifelse(x < 0 & floor(y) == y, 2^(y-1), 2^floor(y)) * .Machine$double.eps
}
```

Have also a look at: [What is the correct/standard way to check if difference is smaller than machine precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59229545/10488504).

Comment: Sorry to be a pain --- I just updated my question.  I'm actually dealing with inputs that are log-probabilities so they are non-positive.

Comment: For those Values the maximum error will be in the range of: `getPrec(0)` gives `4.940656e-324` so values from `0 - 4.940656e-324/2` to `0 + 4.940656e-324/2` will be stored as `0` and `getPrec(exp(0))` gives `2.220446e-16` what gives a range of `1 - 2.220446e-16/2` to `1 + 2.220446e-16/2` for `1`. So your calculated Error of `1.110223e-16` says a `1` is a `1`  but a `1` stored as a float can range from `1 +- 1.110223e-16` so I would say the maximum possible error is in the range of `4.940656e-324 + 2.220446e-16` when only considering the precision of `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I'd suggest using a randomised approach to generate a lot more `x`s, e.g.:

```
x <- runif(10000000, 0, 2)
```

Your regularly spaced values might happen to stumble on a pattern that "just works".

Also it depends on whether you care about absolute error or [relative error](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#689).  The absolute error should be close to `.Machine$double.xmax` while relative error increases as `x` approaches zero.  E.g. `log(exp(1e-16))` gets truncated to zero.