# R all.equal gives different outputs for two comparisons having the same absolute difference

Tags: r

I would like to compare two vectors elementwise with the all.equal function.
Strangely, these two comparisons give different results, and I wonder why it happens.

```
map2(c(1,1,0.7), c(1,1,0.6), all.equal, tolerance = 0.1, scale = 1)

[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE



map2(c(1,1,0.7), c(1,1,0.8), all.equal, tolerance = 0.1, scale = 1)
[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] "Mean absolute difference: 0.1"
```

Since the absolute difference between 0.7 and 0.8 and between 0.6 and 0.7 is the same, I expect to get T for both.

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: `format(0.7 - 0.8, digits = 22); format(0.7 - 0.6, digits = 22)`

Comment: Maybe have also a look at [What is the correct/standard way to check if difference is smaller than machine precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59229545/10488504).

Comment: Thanks everyone, it is clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This relates to floating point precision, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate), and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal).

```r
sprintf("%.54f", 0.7)
#[1] "0.699999999999999955591079014993738383054733276367187500"
sprintf("%.54f", 0.8)
#[1] "0.800000000000000044408920985006261616945266723632812500"
```

So the difference between both is actually `> 0.1`.

---

You can add a small tolerance to remedy this. Actually `.Machine$double.eps^0.5` is the default tolerance for `all.equal`:

```r
map2(c(1,1,0.7), c(1,1,0.8), all.equal, tolerance = 0.1 + .Machine$double.eps^0.5, scale = 1)

[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE
```